# Convert Hexadecimal $8D(16)$ to binary in signed magnitude

Tags: binary, binary-operations

I'm supposed to covert hexadecimal value, $8D(16)$ into $8$-bit binary if signed magnitude representation is used.

$8D(16)$ $\to$ $1000$ $1101(2)$

For signed magnitude, the left most bit is used to signify whether the value is a $+$ or $-$ value. In this case, how do I represent the value 8 into signed magnitude binary? Isn't $1000$ equals to $-0$. I don't see any possible way to write $8D$ in binary

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An 8-bit signed integer has a range of -128 to 127.  But hexadecimal 8D is 141.   So what you're trying to accomplish is impossible.